# How could I check if an element ID exists if is an external source, using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

In my view I have this script used for retrieve an external iframe:

```
var frame = document.getElementById('divFrame');
```

I know that generally it's used `.length` for the job, but in this case, before I need to get the element and then check if exists, since it's from an external page.

Using jQuery how is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check that it exists:

```
if ( $('#divFrame').length ) {
    // Do Something Here
}
```

OR if you want to check if it has loaded:

```
$('#divFrame').load(function (){
    alert("Loaded!!!");
});
```

Comment: but the element is on external subfolder